# HTML/CSS Best way to horizontally align elements inside a div

Tags: css, html

Im working on the followinig:

[image]

The content in the right section (yellow bg) needs to be "stacked" horizontally aligned inside the right section.

***What is the best / easiest way to tackle this problem?***

1. Can I use divs with height percentage?
2. Should I use margins, and negative margins?
3. Should I create separate divs for each piece of content within the right section?

Any help, examples or resources, much appreciated

Comment: you can use `margin : 0 auto` to the whole div under the yellow background.

Comment: can you provide your code so that it would be easy to solve your issue?

Comment: could you provide an image of what you wish the expected output to be please

Comment: @haxxton the desired result is same as image, in the question

Comment: Content 1, content 2 and container div for Content 3 show be separate divs with either `margin-top` on content 2 and container for content 3 and `float:left`.

Inside container for Content 3, you should try a flexbox. See:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/

Comment: @ishaan nice link thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `flexbox`

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.inner {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.inner.nr1,
.inner.nr2 {
  width: 80%;
}
.inner.nr3,
.inner.nr4,
.inner.nr5 {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner nr1">
  </div>
  <div class="inner nr2">
  </div>
  <div class="inner nr3">
  </div>
  <div class="inner nr4">
  </div>
  <div class="inner nr5">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is the first time ive heard about flexbox will read up further.